# Guardar dados Mysql php numa única tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com uma pequena dúvida em guardar um formulário no mysql que é.
Tenho um formulário que está dividido em 2 e quero que seja guardado na mesma tabela.

Quando guardo só faço guardar a segunda parte do mysql ele apaga-me a primeira.

Exemplo Formulario1: Nome, função
Inserir na BD:

```
$sqlinsert = "Insert into tb_trabalhador (Nome, funcao) Values ('".$Nome."','".$Funcao."')";

mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
if ($sqlinsert)
```

Formulario2: Cartaocidadao, data de nascimento
Inserir na BD:

```
$sqlinsert = "Insert into tb_trabalhador (Cartao, Data) Values ('".$Cartao."','".$Data."')";

 mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
 if ($sqlinsert)
```

Comment: Ao que parece você esta recriando a variável e sobrescrevendo a query, poste mais de seu código para que possamos entender.

Comment: mas são duas paginas php diferentes. Não interfere acho eu

Comment: Pode interferir sim. Precisamos ver mais código para poder ajudar.

Comment: São os dois exactamente iguais na parte do insert. So muda é os campos.

Comment: Alterando apenas sqlinsert2 , sqlinsert3... Já pode ajudar a funcionar?

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que me parece que você quer juntar os dados em um registro só, mas está criando dois.

Depois de usar cada um dos seus códigos, você vai ter uma tabela assim:

```
Cartao | Data       | Nome   | Funçao
-------+------------+--------+--------
2136   | 31/05/2014 |        |
-------+------------+--------+--------
       |            | Holmer | Estivador
```

Se quiser acrescentar dados numa tabela, vai precisar de algo assim:

```
$cartao = "2136" // esse é só um exemplo, pode ser ID, aí vai depender do seu caso.
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE tb_trabalhador". // ATUALIZE tb_trabalhador
    "SET Nome=$nome, Funcao=$Funcao". // mudando o nome pra $Nome e função pra $Funcao
    "WHERE Cartao=$Cartao";           // na linha em que o cartão for $Cartao
```

Nota: este é apenas um exemplo. Como já deve ter sido avisado em algumas das suas perguntas anteriores, você deveria estar usando funções do `mysqli_` para poder usar `bindParameter`, em vez de criar a string com parâmetros, mas este ja é outro problema.

Comment: Não irei ter problemas em utilizar o update para acrescentar dados so mysql?

Comment: Provavelmente vai, mas não pelo mesmo motivo ;) . Brincadeiras à parte, a diferença é a seguinte: INSERT é pra acrescentar uma linha nova na tabela, com os dados que você fornecer. UPDATE só altera uma linha já existente, mudando dados das células. Se você colocar 3 informações com INSERT, estará criando 3 linhas (registros diferentes) com todos os campos da tabela, mesmo que vazios. Por outro lado, com UPDATE nunca vai ser criada uma linha nova, ele só serve para atualizar a informação de uma linha existente.

Comment: Vamos fazer uma comparação pra você entender: o INSERT é você pegar um formulário novinho da gaveta, com vários campos vazios, o por o nome do cliente nele, e a idade, e guardar na pasta "clientes". O UPDATE é você pegar algum dos formulários que já está na pasta "clientes" e acrescentar algo, (ou passar corretivo e mudar algo). Aplicando no seu caso: no seu código, você pegou duas fichas de cliente novinhas da gaveta, numa delas colocou o Cartão e a Data. Na outra, colocou Nome e Função, e agora tem duas fichas de cliente na mesma pasta, ambas faltando pedaço.

Comment: uma duvida. se estou a inserir os dados não sei que dados estou a colocar. Como posso fazer o update por algum campo ou por id?